# javascript can I get class from it's name?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is a function in javascript that returns the class if we add a parameter,

for example :

```
myClass extends someClass{

// My code here.

}
```

and somewhere else I could do :

```
let class = getClass("MyClass");
```

Or I should do a registering process (like putting my class in an array...).

Thanks.

Comment: If you know name of the class why not simply referring to it? It's just like a variable.

Comment: What environment (browser, nodejs, etc.)? Is `myClass` in the global scope or in a local scope?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `eval('myClass')` that will return the class, but it won't work with `eval('MyClass')`

Comment: OP wants to get the class by it's name, as it seems by using a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes, I misspelled with "MyClass" and myClass, but it's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Then can you please approve the answer?